# Property 'load' does not exist on type TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have two types are unioned in constructor. I dont know which concrete realization I will get.

```
type TreeLayerActions = {
  load(): void;
}

type TreeMapActions = {
  make(): void;
}

class A {
  constructor(private tree: TreeLayerActions | TreeMapActions) {
     
  }

  load() {
    this.tree.load();
  }

  make() {
    this.tree.make();
  }
}
```

Why I get this error:

```
Property 'load' does not exist on type 'TreeLayerActions | TreeMapActions'.
  Property 'load' does not exist on type 'TreeMapActions'
```

Comment: You might be looking for an intersection type? `TreeLayerActions & TreeMapActions`? Otherwise you'd have to typecheck `tree` each time accessing a property.

Comment: No I need OR condition, or `TreeLayerActions` or `TreeMapActions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to properly discriminate a union:

As the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) says, you can add a literal field which can be checked.

```
type TreeLayerActions = {
    type: "layer";
    load(): void;
}

type TreeMapActions = {
    type: "map";
    make(): void;
}

function doSomethingWithUnion(x: TreeLayerActions | TreeMapActions) {
    switch (x.type) {
    case "map":
        x.make()
        return
    case "layer":
        x.load()
        return
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make your own [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
function isLayer(x: TreeLayerActions | TreeMapActions): x is TreeLayerActions {
    return (x as TreeLayerActions).load !== undefined;
}

function isMap(x: TreeLayerActions | TreeMapActions): x is TreeMapActions {
    return (x as TreeMapActions).make !== undefined;
}

if (isLayer(x)) {
    x.load()
}
```